# Is it possible to detect when VS Code has been active/inactive for a period of time?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension that integrates with a time tracking app. Tasks can be "started" and "ended" manually. However, I would like for this to be automatic when working in VS Code.

It would be great if after ~15 min of inactivity the extension would "end" the task until VS Code became active again.

I imagine using the [onFileSystem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events) activation event could function as a way of starting the task, but not sure how the task could be "ended" automatically.

Comment: Perhaps you can somehow hook into the auto-save functionality. If no changes have been saved in the last 15 minutes, then end the task.

Comment: you can hook on the `selection changed` event (cursor movement)